# How to get control with minimal area from array of controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have an array of controls:

```
Control[] controls = getControls();
```

I need to get the control with minimal area. I know that I can sort it like that and get control in index 0:

```
var min = filtered.OrderBy(x => x.Height * x.Width).ToArray()[0];
```

But how can I fetch it without ordering the controls?

Comment: Why don't you like to order controls?

Comment: I'd like to know why you wouldn't want to use `OrderBy`. Also, the `ToArray()[0]` could be just `First()`.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto var min = filtered.Min(x => x.Height* x.Width) wouldn't work because it would return min area value instead of Control with min area.

Comment: @Aleksandar I never use it, so I forgot how it returns. Removed from my comment, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Enumerable.Aggregate for this. Alas that function will calculate the size of your smallest control over and over again.

If is more efficient (and readable) to create an extension function that takes a sequence of `Controls` and returns the smallest one, similar to all other linq functions. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
// extension function: gets the size of a control
public static int GetSize(this Control control)
{
    return (control.Height * control.Width);
}

// returns the smallest control, by size, or null if there isn't any control
public static Control SmallestControlOrDefault(this IEnumerable<Control> controls)
{
    if (controls == null || !controls.Any()) return null; // default

    Control smallestControl = controls.First();
    int smallestSize = smallestControl.GetSize();

    // check all other controls if they are smaller
    foreach (var control in controls.Skip(1))
    {
        int size = control.GetSize();
        if (size < smallestSize)
        {
             smallestControl = control;
             smallestSize = size;
        }
    }
    return smallestControl;
}
```

The `Skip(1)` will iterate over the first element again. If you don't want this, enumerate using `GetEnumerator` and `MoveNext`:

```
var enumerator = controls.GetEnumerator();
if (enumerator.MoveNext())
{   // there is at least one control
    Control smallestControl = enumerator.Current;
    int smallestSize = smallestControl.GetSize();

    // continue enumerating the other controls, to see if they are smaller
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {   // there are more controls
        Control control = enumerator.Current;
        int size = control.GetSize();
        if (size < smallestSize)
        {   // this control is smaller
            smallestControl = control;
            smallestSize = size;
        }
    }
    return smallestControl;
}
else
{   // empty sequence
    ...
}
```

This way you are absolutely certain that you will enumerate only once

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<Control> controls = ...
Control smallestControl = controls.SmallestControlOrDefault();
```

Comment: I personally like `Aggregate` solution more as it follows OP's `LINQ` approach.

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished thanks to the very powerful but underused [`Aggregate`](https://hryniewski.net/2017/01/06/linq-dont-be-afraid-of-aggregate/) method :

```
var min = controls.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Height * x.Width < y.Height * y.Width ? x : y);
```

You might extend your `Control` class with an `Area` property to avoid the multiplication code repetition in the `Aggregate` method.